# Reference for matrices with all eigenvalues 1 or -1

Tags: reference-request, linear-algebra, matrices

In a homological algebra problem I am in the situation that I have an invertible (over $\mathbb{Z}$) integer matrix $X$ and a permutation matrix $Y$ such that $N:=XY$ is a matrix with all eigenvalues equal to 1 or -1.

> Question 1 : Does such a situation appear already in other situations/fields in algebra/combinatorics? Is there an interpretation for this or does it have a combinatorial meaning?

> Question 2: Do (invertible integer) matrices with all eigenvalues equal to 1 or -1 have a name, or do matrices $X$ as above have a name? Are they studied in the literature?

Comment: A square matrix with only 1 as eigenvalue (in every field extension) is called unipotent. So $M$ has all eigenvalues $\pm 1$ iff $M^2$ is unipotent. I don't know it this has a name.

Comment: @YCor Thanks, this is already helpful for me.

Comment: Hermitian unitary matrices have all eigenvalues equal to $\pm 1$; in the physics context, these are studied as scattering matrices of systems with a chiral symmetry (the trace of this matrix then counts the number of topologically protected "zero-modes").

Comment: @CarloBeenakker OP's matrix has integer entries, if I understand correctly, so it cannot be unitary apart from trivial cases (signed permutation matrices).

Comment: Your matrix is conjugate (via an invertible integral matrix) to an upper triangular matrix with each main diagonal entry $\pm 1$. I'm not sure that much more can be said, since any matrix with that property has all eigenvalues $\pm 1$.

Comment: It's not hard to construct two projections preserving the generalized eigenspaces (by adding/subtracting $I_n$ and dividing by $2$/$-2$ if your matrix is diagonalizable), so projections may be a place to start.

Comment: Hi @GeoffRobinson, would it be okay for you to provide a reference for your result? (I found it a bit difficult to prove, as such a matrix is not similar to its Jordan normal form via an invertible integral matrix in general)

Comment: I meant that the matrix $N$ is conjugate in the above way to an upper triangular matrix with all diagonal entries $\pm1.$

Comment: @GeoffRobinson Thank you, could you tell me where I can find the proof for this result: an invertible integral matrix with all eigenvalue ±1 is conjugate to an upper triangular matrix with all diagonal entries ±1 via an integral matrix

Comment: You work by induction on $n$. Identify the $n$-long integerr column vectors with $\mathbb{Z}^{n}$. We may choose a non zero integral column  vector $v$ with $Nv = \pm v$, and we may arrange so that the entries of $v$ have gcd 1, which means that $v$ may be extended to a $\mathbb{Z}$-basis for the integer column vectors. This reduces the problem to rank $n-1$ with a little thought.